Google Sign-In Dialog Not Opening in Flutter InAppWebView
I'm using Flutter's InAppWebView to open a website that includes Google Sign-In functionality. However, the Google Sign-In dialog or options are not opening when I interact with the website. Instead, I see console logs like TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'google.accounts.id').
Here are some details:
The website works fine on a normal browser and opens the Google Sign-In dialog without issues.
I have added the required permissions in my Flutter app, including INTERNET in AndroidManifest.xml and appropriate configurations for iOS.
The InAppWebView is rendering other parts of the website correctly, but the Google Sign-In feature fails.
How can I resolve this issue and ensure the Google Sign-In dialog opens within the InAppWebView?
1 I used the InAppWebView widget to load the website that contains the Google Sign-In functionality.
2 Verified that the website and Google Sign-In dialog work correctly in standard web browsers like Chrome and Safari.
3 Ensured the required permissions, like INTERNET for Android and appropriate entitlements for iOS, are set in the app.
4 Added debugging to capture console messages, which showed errors like TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'google.accounts.id').
5 Checked if cookies and JavaScript were enabled in the InAppWebView settings.
What I Expected:
I expected the Google Sign-In dialog to open seamlessly within the InAppWebView when interacting with the login button on the website, just like it does on a regular browser.

Please provide your code on how you initialize Google sign-in in your app.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You can read if you are expecting to attract more potential answers.
